# How to add uncheck flag argument thought CMD command to msbuild

Tags: sql-server, msbuild

I dropped in one of my sql table one column, and tried to published it thought VS.
I got error for data loss could occur, and it got fixed by uncheck the checkbox of 'Block incremental deployment if data loss might occur'.
How I can do the same from CMD using MS build command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was given [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/141977):

use the `/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=True/False` command-line option